# CakePHP 3 : Class 'Cake\Routing\DispatcherFactory' not found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, dispatcher, internal-server-error

I have developed an application in `CakePHP 3`. It was working fine in my `localhost` server but when I uploaded it to shared hosting it started giving `500 Internal server error`

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@main-hosting.eu to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

I tried all solutions on google but nothing helped.
Then I located php error log and found these lines in it.

```
[19-Jun-2016 18:29:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Cake\Routing\DispatcherFactory' not found in /home/username/public_html/webroot/index.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/username/public_html/webroot/index.php on line 33
```

Content of /webroot/index.php is

```
<?php
/**
 * The Front Controller for handling every request
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since         0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */
// for built-in server
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server') {
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/' . basename(__FILE__);

    $url = parse_url(urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    $file = __DIR__ . $url['path'];
    if (strpos($url['path'], '..') === false && strpos($url['path'], '.') !== false && is_file($file)) {
        return false;
    }
}
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/bootstrap.php';

use Cake\Network\Request;
use Cake\Network\Response;
use Cake\Routing\DispatcherFactory;

$dispatcher = DispatcherFactory::create();    // Line 33
$dispatcher->dispatch(
    Request::createFromGlobals(),
    new Response()
);
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: The error pretty much says it all, the class `DispatcherFactory` in the `Cake\Routing` namespace could not be found/read. Check that your CakePHP installation is complete (did you run `composer install`?) and the ownership and permissions on files and folders are set correctly so that the php process can read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using shared hosting then please check for file and folder permissions:

1. All files in your cake project must have 644 permission

> 644 means that files are readable and writeable by the owner of the file and readable by users in the group owner of that file and readable by everyone else.

2. All Folder in your cake project must have 755 permission

> 755 is the same thing, it just has the execute bit set for everyone. The execute bit is needed to be able to change into the directory. This is why directories are commonly set to 755.

3. Check All Extension and Configuration to run your Cake project and also check whether rewrite module is working or not.

Hope this works for you...

Comment: All permissions are well. Directories are `755` and Files are `644`. Also directory `tmp` and it's `sub-directories` are set to `777`. Yes, `mod_rewrite` is not available by hosting provider but installation guide by cakephp says `Having mod_rewrite is preferred, but by no means required`. Also when I use to browse for any controller that does not exists show error page as usual error page with message `Controller not found` but while accessing controller that actually exists gives `500 Internal Server` error.

Comment: Also I'm able to access few controllers whiles few are giving `500 Internal Server` error. I am able to access [http://flitfix.com/users/login](http://flitfix.com/users/login) but access to [http://flitfix.com/users/register](http://flitfix.com/users/register) gives `500 Internal Server` error

Comment: In above comment you have mention that `mod_rewrite` is not available so this is cause of your error. Raise support ticket to hosting provider and tell them to enable `mod_rewrite` module for apache. Actually without `mod_rewrite` your `.htaccess` file will not work.

Comment: I knew it. But it has been mentioned by CakePHP in their installation guide that `mod_rewrite is preferred but by no means required` Also few actions are working well. Like `login` action of `UsersController` by `register` action of same class not working. Even the home page is working which shows all configuration as correct.

Comment: I also tried disabling mod_rewrite and deleting .htaccess files to make url pretty as `http://flitfix.com/index.php/users/register` but it also gives same error